# Modify indicator - increase distance between icon and text

Tags: unity, themes, icons, indicator

This is my second question about theming an indicator-applet.

With the theme I'm using (FlatStudio,it doesn't matter if Grey, Dark etc...), there is one small annoying bug: The distance between the icon for the battery and the text is too small (See screenshot). The same thing happens for the online-status icons...

What css files do I have to edit, in order to increase this distance?

[image: icon too close to label]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append these lines to `/usr/share/themes/FlatStudio/gtk-3/menu_frame.css`:

```
/* Add right padding for all child images in menu items */
.menuitem GtkImage {
    padding-right: 4px;
}

/* Remove padding for last last icon, like the one in session indicator */
.menuitem GtkImage:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Samething for other variant themes dark, blue,.. This is a screenshot with 25px (just to make it clear)

[image: fix icon padding in flatstudio theme]